# Google app engine- python dev_appserver_main.py

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried to run  a GAE project  and when I was using command : dev_appserver.py, I got this error message(complete one)
:

```
WARNING  2011-07-26 04:25:29,342 urlfetch_stub.py:108] No ssl package found. url
fetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
INFO     2011-07-26 04:25:29,515 appengine_rpc.py:159] Server: appengine.google.
com
INFO     2011-07-26 04:25:29,530 appcfg.py:456] Checking for updates to the SDK.

INFO     2011-07-26 04:25:33,875 appcfg.py:473] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2011-07-26 04:25:33,890 datastore_file_stub.py:511] Could not read data
store data from d:\360data\重要数据\用户临~1\dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2011-07-26 04:25:33,890 rdbms_sqlite.py:58] Connecting to SQLite databa
se '' with file 'd:\\360data\\\xd6\xd8\xd2\xaa\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd\\\xd3\xc3\xbb\xa7
\xc1\xd9~1\\dev_appserver.rdbms'
ERROR    2011-07-26 04:25:33,890 dev_appserver_main.py:638] <class 'sqlite3.Oper
ationalError'>: unable to open database file
```

I searched for the solution, and I got sample answers like "including Unicode and can't get my user name or use the launcher with admin flag or delete the 'dev_appserver.rdbms' file" , but I'm not clear with that(what exactly to do), how to solve this problem, I can't get the file 'dev_appserver.rdbms', because the path "'d:\360data\\xd6\xd8\xd2\xaa\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd\\xd3\xc3\xbb\xa7\xc1\xd9~1\" does not exist after "d:\360data\", this prob taunts me and I can't go on , hope I can get a clear guidance from you :>

Comment: What command line arguments are you specifying? Are you running the dev_appserver from that directory?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you try to launch the Google App Engine Launcher?  Does it start?  If so, try to add the project to the launcher and run it.  Do you get the same error message?